# Change configurable product price selecting a swatch

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

Good morning,
i'm working on a magento 2.2.5 store and i have a question about configurable products configurations.
I have some products where the price is different betweent the configurations.
Example: 
Configurable product: Hat
Red hat costs 10$; Blue hat costs 15$.

If i click on the blue visual swatch  the product image updates, but the product price is always the same (the lowest).
If i add the blue product in the cart the price is the correct one.
My question is that: it is possible to update the price is the product page clicking on the visual swatch? it is a bug of magento or maybe of my theme?

Thanks

Comment: I have 2.2.5 and the price changes when changing a product configuration. I suggest you revert back to the luma theme and see if the error reproduces.

Comment: Does it reload the photo and edit the product price when you select a color swatch?

Comment: Yes. If the simple products have different images. they get changed. Also the product price. It works as expected.

Comment: Yeah i tried on a luma theme demo on the web and it work. it is probaly my theme, but i have to understand where to fix it

Comment: check that the markup for the price in your theme is similar to the one in the luma theme

Comment: yes but the price box it is not clearly update clicking on the swatches

Comment: Yeah it simply not ajax reload the price. Console is empty, logs too, i really don't know how to fix it

Comment: There should not be an ajax call. All price configurations should be loaded upfront and just changed via js

Comment: yeah it was a theme problem

Comment: @baronebirra would care to explain what modification you did to cause the issue and how did you fix it? Like was it the customization of the Magento_Catalog module for example or something else?